# Одноклассники API. Как отправить комментарий к посту от имени группы. (Пост принадлежит группе)

Tags: api, rest, graph, одноклассники

Перерыл всю их дурацкую документацию, нигде не вижу что это возможно. Но в одном из сервисов, ребята это все-таки как-то делают.